# running tex from php script

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion, tex

I've installed mactex on my macbook and configured apache + php + mysql.

So when I'm running texi2pdf from bash it works fine. But when I'm trying to run it from php script the next error occurs

```
Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

The function is called as

```
exec("texi2pdf .... ")
```

$PATH var is OK.

I guess the problem with access to some files but I've set permission to all necessary files (including *~/Library/texlive*) and all of them are successfully read with

```
exec("ls ... ")
```

or

```
exec("cat ...")
```

The problem is not with cyrillic fonts, all necessary packages are installed and as I've already said texi2pdf works fine from bash.

---

*MacOSX 10.7*

*Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6*

*TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)*

Comment: Have you tried `pdflatex` (or `pdfetex`) directly?

Comment: Yes, I've tried pdflatex. Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
As PHP script uses current directory (or DocumentRoot) to load and generate necessary tex fonts the home directory should be change to user home

```
putenv('HOME=/Users/username');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to allow exec? It may be blocked as default.

Comment: Other commands like exec("ls") works fine. And shell_exec and system and passthru also works.